# Make pandas.pivot_table observed=False create missing columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

So it's supposed that when passing the argument observed=False to pandas.pivot_table should create missing columns but it doesn't.

In my example, I have a categorical column "hours", and I want to get the whole 24 columns even if input data has not all the hours.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([["user_1", 23],
                   ["user_1", 22],
                   ["user_2", 21]],
                  columns=["user", "hour"]).set_index("user")
df["hour"] = pd.Categorical.from_codes(df["hour"], categories=range(24))
df = df.assign(count=True)
df.pivot_table(columns="time",
               index="user",
               values="count",
               fill_value=False,
               observed=False,
              )
```

Output I get:

```
        22      23
user        
user_1  True    True
user_2  True    False
```

Expected output:

```
        0       ... 22      23
user        
user_1  False   ... True    True
user_2  False   ... True    False
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can skip the `Categorical` and do a `reindex` on `axis=1` after pivot:

```
df.pivot_table(columns="hour",
               index="user",
               values="count",
               fill_value=False,
               observed=False,
              ).reindex(range(24), axis=1, fill_value=False)


hour       0      1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9      10     11     12     13     14     15     16     17     18     19     20     21     22     23
user                                                                                                                                                                          
user_1  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False   True   True
user_2  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False   True  False  False
```